# Maven Failsafe runs no tests

Tags: maven

Mutimodule project with root pom.xml:

```
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.failsafe.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/**IT*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
   </build>
```

and in the sub-project:

```
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.failsafe.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

Nothing jumps out at me using -X. 
I have legit tests in the default dir, which according to the docs is `src/it/java`. I've tried install, verify and integration-test.

```
[DEBUG]   (s) reportFormat = brief
[DEBUG]   (s) reportsDirectory = C:\Ws\gitproject\subproject\target\failsafe-reports
[DEBUG]   (f) rerunFailingTestsCount = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) reuseForks = true
[DEBUG]   (s) runOrder = filesystem
[DEBUG]   (f) shutdown = testset
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipAfterFailureCount = 0
[DEBUG]   (s) skipTests = false
[DEBUG]   (s) suiteXmlFiles = []
[DEBUG]   (s) summaryFile = C:\Ws\gitproject\subproject\target\failsafe-reports\failsafe-summary.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) tempDir = surefire
[DEBUG]   (s) testClassesDirectory = C:\Ws\gitproject\subproject\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   (s) testNGArtifactName = org.testng:testng
[DEBUG]   (s) testSourceDirectory = C:\Ws\gitproject\subproject\src\test\java
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCountClasses = 0
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCountMethods = 0
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCountSuites = 0
[DEBUG]   (s) trimStackTrace = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useFile = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useManifestOnlyJar = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useSystemClassLoader = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useUnlimitedThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (s) workingDirectory = C:\Ws\gitproject\subproject
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: com.superchicken.otm:subproject:18.2.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Ws\gitproject\subproject\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@306863ac
```

testSourceDirectory doesn't look right to me but I've been unable to change it so far. I'll verify that momentarily.

--correction. It's not that I'm not able to change testSourceDirectory, but doing so does not improve matters.

Additional info: We are also running jacoco and fortify.

New information: The files in `src/it/**/*.java` are not compiling. The class files don't end up in the target directory any where.

Comment: The default directory for tests is `src/test/java`..the naming convention for integration test is `*IT.java` and it's the default so there is no need to make an include for that...

Comment: I have one test case that is named **/*ITCase.java and all others are *ITest.java That's why the modification but either should work with the above inlcude and neither does.

Comment: I'ma try an updated version of maven.

Comment: What's your maven execution command ?

Comment: mvn clean integration-test. Maven update to 3.5.3 did not help.

Comment: You don't specify the sub-module with `-pl` ?

Comment: No, just change to the sub-directory and run.

Comment: You should follow the naming conventions first and try to invent your own conventions..Please make an example project on Github so we can take a look.

Comment: And does the sub model points to the parent POM ? Can you please share the whole POM files ?

Comment: The regular code builds fine so, yes. I will share the pom files but it may take some time to redact and of course, I have plenty more to do besides. ...so it won't be right away.

Comment: OK, so as updated in the problem description, the integration tests are not compiling.